# Dynamic grouping in a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grouping

I have a list with some items.
The items have a name, creation date, modification date, an owner and some other properties.

I want to diplay them in a WPF ListView and group them.
They shall be grouped a column selected from a dropdown (no grouping, group by name, group by owner, group by creation date).

I know how to bild a list view, bind the item list and createing a static group. There are a lot of good examples fpr static groups.

I need enabling/disabling grouping and changing the group.
How can ythis be done in WPF?
Clemens Hoffmann

Comment: look at ICollectionView for grouping, sorting, filtering

Comment: The first result of "wpf listview grouping" leads to [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/). Changing `GroupDescription` would be what you call *dynamic*.